# Dump JSON without escape sequence

Tags: json, django

I would like to dump my django model as a JSON file in order to use it to show points on a map by using leaflet. However, when I dump the JSON file it creates additional escape sequences for double quotes in JSON file. How do I create and save JSON file  without escape sequences is my question.

Below it is my code in views.py.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
def JSON(request):
 queryset = Poi.objects.all()
 queryset = serializers.serialize('json', queryset)
 queryset = queryset[:0] +'markers =' + queryset[0:]
 with open (r'C:\Users\Savas\Desktop\MY_WEB_PROJECTS\WEB_TOOLS\web_tools\static\js\queryset.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(queryset, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
 return HttpResponse(queryset, content_type="application/json")
```

Here is the JSON file:

```
"markers =[{\"model\": \"project.poi\", \"pk\": 28, \"fields\": {\"name_site\": \"gtrgr\", \"number_order\": 15156, \"latitude\": 58.5, \"longitude\": 15.4, \"a_measured_height_lt\": 2.5, \"k_measured_height_lt\": 2.6}}, {\"model\": \"project.poi\", \"pk\": 29, \"fields\": {\"name_site\": \"Sik sok\", \"number_order\": 568956, \"latitude\": 56.9, \"longitude\": 1.5, \"a_measured_height_lt\": 2.5, \"k_measured_height_lt\": 3.6}}, {\"model\": \"project.poi\", \"pk\": 30, \"fields\": {\"name_site\": \"freg\", \"number_order\": 189465, \"latitude\": 34.6, \"longitude\": 16.5, \"a_measured_height_lt\": 2.5, \"k_measured_height_lt\": 2.5}}, {\"model\": \"project.poi\", \"pk\": 31, \"fields\": {\"name_site\": \"dewf\", \"number_order\": 1856, \"latitude\": 26.6, \"longitude\": 10.0, \"a_measured_height_lt\": 5.6, \"k_measured_height_lt\": 2.6}}, {\"model\": \"project.poi\", \"pk\": 32, \"fields\": {\"name_site\": \"nhfmh\", \"number_order\": 156, \"latitude\": 54.5, \"longitude\": 26.5, \"a_measured_height_lt\": 2.6, \"k_measured_height_lt\": 1.7}}, {\"model\": \"project.poi\", \"pk\": 35, \"fields\": {\"name_site\": \"vfv\", \"number_order\": 651561, \"latitude\": 56.8, \"longitude\": 89.5, \"a_measured_height_lt\": 5.2, \"k_measured_height_lt\": 2.6}}]"
```

And here is the JSON fiel when I removed the escape sequences:

```
markers =[{"model": "project.poi", "pk": 28, "fields": {"name_site": "gtrgr", "number_order": 15156, "latitude": 58.5, "longitude": 15.4, "a_measured_height_lt": 2.5, "k_measured_height_lt": 2.6}}, {"model": "project.poi", "pk": 29, "fields": {"name_site": "Sik sok", "number_order": 568956, "latitude": 56.9, "longitude": 1.5, "a_measured_height_lt": 2.5, "k_measured_height_lt": 3.6}}, {"model": "project.poi", "pk": 30, "fields": {"name_site": "freg", "number_order": 189465, "latitude": 34.6, "longitude": 16.5, "a_measured_height_lt": 2.5, "k_measured_height_lt": 2.5}}, {"model": "project.poi", "pk": 31, "fields": {"name_site": "dewf", "number_order": 1856, "latitude": 26.6, "longitude": 10.0, "a_measured_height_lt": 5.6, "k_measured_height_lt": 2.6}}, {"model": "project.poi", "pk": 32, "fields": {"name_site": "nhfmh", "number_order": 156, "latitude": 54.5, "longitude": 26.5, "a_measured_height_lt": 2.6, "k_measured_height_lt": 1.7}}, {"model": "project.poi", "pk": 35, "fields": {"name_site": "vfv", "number_order": 651561, "latitude": 56.8, "longitude": 89.5, "a_measured_height_lt": 5.2, "k_measured_height_lt": 2.6}}]
```

Comment: A JSON file with unescaped double quotes inside a string is no longer a valid JSON file. Why do you not want double quotes escaped? What's the purpose of such a file?

Comment: I am using that JSON file in order to show points on OpenStreetMap by using leaflet.js and somehow my points is not shown on the map with a JSON file with escape sequences.

Comment: The reason why the points are not showing has to be something else. What makes you suspect that the escaped double quotes are the cause?

Comment: When I remove the escape sequences from the JSON file the points are shown. I tried that it works.

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample of the JSON file before and after the removal of the escaped double quotes?

Comment: Yes, please find it above.

Comment: Why are you trying to write the file including the literal `markers =` assignment? That's not a valid thing to have in a JSON file.

Comment: Because I use that JSON file in a javascript to show points on a map and in javascript code I refer to JSON file as "markers" in a for loop in order to get the coordinates.